# kafka to hdfs with confluent source code

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

For the requirement of my project, I need to build a class from the confluent java code to write data from kafka topic to the hdfs filesystem.

It is actually working in CLI with connect-standalone, but I need to do the same thing with the source code which I built successfully.

I have a problem with SinkTask and hdfsConnector classes.
An exception is showing up in the put method.

Here below is my class code:

```
package io.confluent.connect.hdfs;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.sink.SinkConnector;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.sink.SinkRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.sink.SinkTaskContext;

import io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData;
import io.confluent.connect.hdfs.avro.AvroFormat;
import io.confluent.connect.hdfs.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner;
import io.confluent.connect.storage.common.StorageCommonConfig;
import io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.PartitionerConfig;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;
import org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef;

public class main{
    private static Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<>(); 
    protected static final TopicPartition TOPIC_PARTITION = new TopicPartition(TOPIC, PARTITION);
      protected static String url = "hdfs://localhost:9000";
    protected static SinkTaskContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HdfsSinkConnector hk = new HdfsSinkConnector();
        HdfsSinkTask h = new HdfsSinkTask();
        props.put(StorageCommonConfig.STORE_URL_CONFIG, url);
        props.put(HdfsSinkConnectorConfig.HDFS_URL_CONFIG, url);
        props.put(HdfsSinkConnectorConfig.FLUSH_SIZE_CONFIG, "3");
        props.put(HdfsSinkConnectorConfig.FORMAT_CLASS_CONFIG, AvroFormat.class.getName());    
        try {
            hk.start(props);
            Collection<SinkRecord> sinkRecords = new ArrayList<>();
            SinkRecord record = new SinkRecord("test", 0, null, null, null, null, 0);
            sinkRecords.add(record);
            h.initialize(context);
            h.put(sinkRecords);
            hk.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ConnectException("Couldn't start HdfsSinkConnector due to configuration error", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: " An excepltion showing up in the put method" --> what was the exception? You need to provide more information. Also, what is it that you're writing custom in the code that you couldn't do with the vanilla instance? Is it processing that would be better suited to Kafka Streams or KSQL?

Comment: the exception is Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Couldn't start HdfsSinkConnector due to configuration error
 at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.main.main(main.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkTask.put(HdfsSinkTask.java:109)
 at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.main.main(main.java:57)

Comment: I didn't get the second part, would you please clear that to me ?

Comment: Connect isn't meant to be ran like this

Comment: Then, How I can implement it to my application, I am trying here to avoid making this process through the command line, that's why I had the idea to develop this class ?

Comment: Connect isn't really even meant to be used in standalone mode except for local development. The true power of Connect is the distributed mode which runs an scalable, durable, fault-tolerant consumer. For example, how do you plan on scaling this? Multiple machines won't be work because offsets are not stored anywhere except locally

Comment: And distributed mode doesn't "run in the CLI" except for the initial startup (similar to Kafka or Zookeeper Server). I'm also curious how you planned on actually running this other than from the command line? `java` command needs ran somewhere. All you're doing here is just essentially copying the existing `ConnectStandalone` class, but hard-coding the configurations rather than loading a property file https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/cli/ConnectStandalone.java